# Do GPU's have physically reconfigured parts like FPGAs?

Tags: gpu, fpga

Trying to learn more about GPU's but there's a shortage of info out there I've noticed. (Or I'm terrible at finding it!)

Anyways, my question is whether GPUs have physically reconfigurable parts the way FPGA's do. That is, do they have physical gates and so one that are actually/physically created and changed, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, GPUs are just a different kind of processor (or rather a large number of processors) running software with some communication between them to ensure they keep sufficiently in step to produce correct results.

---

Aside:

FPGAs don't really have "physically" reconfigurable parts - just electronic switches and a collection of bits inside which act as look-up-tables to implement small logic functions.  In addition, there are some blocks of memory and arithmetic blocks.  And a shed-load of wires!  Someone once said that when you buy an FPGA you are buying lot of routing and the logic is thrown in for free.

These LUTs, memorys, DSPs and switches are then linked up to create an arbitrarily (within the limits of what's in the device of course) complex functionality, which can be thought of "as-if-it-were" some gates.

Comment: Interesting. I think I used the wrong language then, it's not a physical thing icic. Hmm, so GPU's don't then "route" some of it's processors to do say Task Set A and another set of its processors to act as a group and do say Task Set B? Or do they do all the same things. Basically, could I have a GPU act FPGA-esque: one part doing one thing, and another part acting independently, doing another thing?   Thanks for your help!

Comment: GPUs (as far as I recall) tend to be set up so that all the processors do much the same thing (in the jargon they all run the same "kernel")  I guess you could write a kernel which says "processor 1 do this thing, processor 2 do that thing", but I think it would be self defeating

Comment: I see you point. The whole power of the GPU is to do things in a massively parallel fashion. Segmenting it would remove that value. Okay, cool. Thanks for you help. Much clearer.